# Flexbox/Float - 2 1 2 Layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a 2 1 2 layout using Flexbox or floats as seen in the image added to this question. Is there any way to do this successfully using just an ordered list of items?

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

[image]

1,2,4,5 are the same in size and 3 is the same width as the other blocks.

I'm trying to accomplish this using Flexbox but I can't seem the get 2 under 1 and 5 under 4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this with `flex-direction: column` and `flex-wrap: wrap` but i think you must set **fixed height on parent**

```css
body, html, ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh; 
  list-style-type: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
li {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 50px;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```