# Flexbox 2/1/2 layout children

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a 2 1 2 flexbox layout as seen in my previous question; [Flexbox/Float - 2 1 2 Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36724124/flexbox-float-2-1-2-layout).

The layout in the answer works, but it's making the children become flex as well and I'm trying to fix this.

[image]

I'd like the text to be underneath the pictures instead of next to it but can't seem to make this work.

```
.mustReadImage img {
    width: 334px;
    height: 222px;
    display: block;
}/*Image*/
.mustReadN {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    display: flex;
    width: 334px;
}/*li*/

.mustReadN:nth-child(3) {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
}/*Big li*/

.mustReadN:nth-child(3) img {
    width: 670px;
    height: 680px;
}/*Big Li Image*/
.mustReadGroup {
    display: flex;
    height: 670px;
    list-style-type: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 74%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}/*Ul*/
```

The li's have children as well.

edit 1; It has to become something like this.

[image]

Comment: How about this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/558/?

Comment: Your image is completely unintelligible. I don't see any relationship between that image and your previous question. It's not clear at all what is the desired result. You didn't include your HTML.

Comment: This is drupal. I'll edit the question with what it has to become.

Comment: The bottom image is what it has to be after the styling.

Comment: Never mind. I fixed it using @NenadVracar 's fiddle. Can you create an answer?

Comment: Its something like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/559/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This fiddle from @NenadVracar had the answer!

```
body,
html,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  list-style-type: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

li:nth-child(3) {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

flex-direction: column; fixed it for me.