# Flexbox column layout: 1 to left and two stacked on right

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to achieve the following responsive grid-layout using flexbox, but i can't manage to get the "desktop"-version right without a fixed height. I want #1 to be on its own to the left and #2 and #3 stacked on each other to the right (#1 does not have to have the same height as the right col)

[image]

HTML (simplified)

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="col1"></div>
    <div class="col2"></div>
    <div class="col3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS (simplified)

```
.wrapper {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #c4c4c4
}

.col1, .col2, .col3 {
  background: #fe4c4c;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: sans-serif;

  min-height: 100px;

  &:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}

.col1 {
  &:after {
    content: '1';
  }

  width: 100px;
}

.col2 {
  &:after {
    content: '2';
  }

  width: calc(100% - (100px + 60px))
}

.col3 {
  &:after {
    content: '3';
  }

  width: calc(100% - 30px);
}

.inner {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {  
  .inner {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .col1 {
    width: 300px;
  }

  .col2 {
    width: auto;
  } 

  .col3 {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

**jsFiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/pcwudrmc/28053/

I've search around for similar problems but can't find an answer without fixed height.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use css grid?

Comment: Is it safe to use? :D @SeanStopnik

Comment: It all depends on how far back you need to support: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid

Answer (score 2):

Solution using CSS grid:

https://codepen.io/seanstopnik/pen/bd511c728bb79d02d11ae04edbfe9a33

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
  padding: 10px;
}

.col1,
.col2,
.col3 {
  background: #fe4c4c;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  font: {
    family: sans-serif;
    size: 40px;
    weight: 700;
  }
  min-height: 100px;

  &:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}

.col1:after {
  content: '1';
}

.col2:after {
  content: '2';
}

.col3:after {
  content: '3';
}


// Inner
.inner {
  display: grid;
  grid: {
    template-columns: 100px auto;
    template-rows: 100px;
    gap: 10px 10px;
  }

  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    grid-template-columns: 300px auto;
  }
}

.col1 {

  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    grid: {
      column: 1 / span 1;
      row: 1 / span 2;
    }
  }
}

.col3 {
  grid: {
    column: 1 / span 2;
    row: 2 / span 2;
  }

  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    grid: {
      column: auto;
      row: auto;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**It can be done with Flexbox.**

Based on the [answer of Nenad Vracar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36724246/895741) to this question [Flexbox/Float - 2 1 2 Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36724124/flexbox-float-2-1-2-layout) I did this:

```css
body,
html,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  list-style-type: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
li {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 50px;
}
li:nth-child(1) {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
```

```html
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
```

It gives you one item to the left with 100% height and two stacked one over the other on the right with 50% height each. This is the result:

[image]